# Java text clustering library

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, data-mining

Which of the data mining java libraries can do text clusterization?

Comment: What do you mean by "text clusterization"? I tried to google it and it has no idea. Do you mean Document Clustering?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this tututorial http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/cluster/read-me.html.
Also you can try carrot(http://search.carrot2.org/stable/search)

Answer (score 5):

[Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Comment: Where is the clustering in Solr?